# Drawing a green outline around the scanned QR/bar code real object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, zxing

I am trying the following in c# Unity3D.

I want to decode a QR Code, and if the identification is successful then draw a green square around the QR code. The square has to track the real object with the decoded text underneath. At the moment I am able to decode the QR, in this [way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PzsLl.png).

[ScanQRCodeVuforia](https://github.com/philipromeo/QRCodeScanner/blob/master/QRScanner/Assets/ScanQRCodeVuforia.cs) is the file where vuforia scan the qr/bar code.

Using the code underneath I am able to detect X and Y which Debug.DrawLine on the screen, but what happens is that the line is parallel to the camera and not on the screen. Just to give you an [idea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLT9o.png). Do you know how can I represent the line on the canvas? Do you know any other method that I can use to draw a green box around the qr?

```
ResultPoint[] point = result.ResultPoints;
Debug.Log("X: " + point[0].X + " Y: " + point[1].Y);
Debug.DrawLine(new Vector3(point[0].X, 0), new Vector3(point[0].Y, 0), Color.green, 1000000000f);
```

I think that this is a good [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21544324/zxing-finding-the-bounding-rectangle-of-barcode) to use to detect the four angles points of the QR.

Thanks.

---

#### Update!

Using the following code, I am able to draw line on the canvas, but it does not result to be align with the image. [This image gives a better idea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhnMO.png)

```
var rayX = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(new Vector3(point[0].X, point[1].Y));
var rayY = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(new Vector3(point[1].Y, point[0].X));
Debug.DrawLine(rayX.origin, rayY.origin, Color.green, 1000000000f);
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you shouldn't use Debug.DrawLine for actually drawing a Line. Its is used for Debugging Purposes only. To do it the right way, use a [LineRenderer](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-LineRenderer.html)

Since you don't seem to have a lot of experience in computer graphics, I'll give you a brief explanation:

What you are trying to achieve is basically visualising the bounding box of an object. According to some other question, the ResultPoint-Array contains 3 points: Bottom-Left, Top-Left and Top-Right. Calculating Bottom-Right is trivial, after that simple draw lines between the points. For example:

```
ResultPoint[] boundingBoxPoints = result.ResultPoints;
Debug.DrawLine(boundingBoxPoints[0], boundingBoxPoints[1], Color.green, 100f);
```

And so on.